# Symfony DateTime returns null when form is submitted

Tags: forms, datetime, symfony

I have a form setup with a `DateTimeType` like this:

```
->add('createdOn', DateTimeType::class, [
            'widget' => 'single_text',              
            'data' => $this->date,
            'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm',
            'input' => 'datetime',
        ]);
```

The html renders exactly as I would expect it to with a value of something like this `2016-11-29 05:57`, but when I submit the form it says the datetime is null. Not sure why this is happening. The created on field is a datetime type in the database.

If I remove all options and set the form type like this:
`->add('createdOn', DateTimeType::class)`
it works fine. The problem I have with that is the style doesn't match my css. I want it to be in a single input box with a datetime displayed.

Let me know what other info you may need.

EDIT: Here is the controller action:

```
$form = $this->createForm(JobTitleFormType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $jobTitle = $form->getData();          

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($jobTitle);
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash('success', 'Job Title "' . $form->get("jobTitle")->getData(). '" has been added.');

        //return new Response($email);
        return $this->redirectToRoute('setup_jobtitles');
    }

    return $this->render('setup/job-titles/job-titles-new.html.twig', [
        'jobTitleForm' => $form->createView(),
        'user' => $loggedInUser,
    ]);
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the code where you use: `$form->get("createdOn")->getData()` and check for a submitted form and persist the data.

Comment: @AlvinBunk I added it to my question.

Comment: Have you used any browser debugging tools to see why the css styling doesn't match? Also, maybe posting a link to [imgur](http://imgur.com/) with a picture of what it looks like and what you want it to look like might be helpful.